# Need Test jig for pass transistors

Tags: transistors, test

I am trying to find a schematic for a test jig.  I have  quite a few 2N5886 and MJ15003 TO3 transistors that I purchased and would like to make sure they meet specs.  Short of building a separate regulated 28 volt supply and putting them in it, how can I test these transistors to make sure they are not going to fail in circuit when being called upon to deliver 28v at 10 amps (for a pair)?

Thank you.

Comment: If you bought them from a dubious source they might be counterfeit. It might be cheaper to throw them out and get known good ones. Are you using them as a switch or in linear mode? If the latter, you will have to mount them and cause them to dissipate realistic power levels. You can use the diode method to measure Tj. You can also open the cans up on a couple and look at the die size and maybe markings.

Comment: P.S. Fake 2SB817 vs. real from [this](http://www.amplabs.co.uk/Transistor%20fakes.htm) web page [here](http://www.amplabs.co.uk/images/fake%20ptran.jpg)

Comment: At these current and voltage levels, with power at 100 watts +, you'll need to test by building into the final circuit, especially the heat sink, then testing the circuit.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're not testing for fakes here, just ones that can stand up to your application. Is that correct - are you trying to make a burn-in test fixture?

Comment: Pass transistors cannot have 28V across them with 10A but the output to ground can be 28V  . Pls advise worst case drop (Vmin)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to test for fakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a Test Engineer after R&D for decades, I like these kind of questions.

If you are wanting only "one" single most important test and have it only take 1 second in a socket, this is the one you want to do.

## Vce(sat)=1.0V max @Ic=15A pulsed @ Ic/Ib=10

See Note 3, pulse duration is not that critical just low duty cycle for no heat sink needed to keep at 25'C  **(N.B.!!)**

I could design a TO-3 socket test fixture (with an Astable pulse gen) to drive a repetitive low freq. 100us pulse from a 10 Ohm source into a 3 Ohm load or use a Vcc=3.3V and change the values then measure the pulsed Vce with a S&H and DMM or a scope.  ESR of source must be included for base drive R **(N.B.)**

Here is the setup for PNP which is merely the inverse for NPN from the datasheet which is **always** the reference circuit you want to emulate with minor changes as required. Proper short (low ESL) signals & ground wires are essential to accurate signal measurement to avoid ringing.

[image]
This will only verify what the Mfg verifies in their automated test, but will not guarantee your design will work. **(N.B.!!)**  But hopefully the design of the LDO was done correctly.